# Folder Object - closing handle

Tags: jsx, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

i have made an illustrator script which is generally quick saving eps into different folders. 
everything works fine, except for the last created folder as it seems like illustrator does not properly close the folder object handle. the result is that i can move or delete every single file in this folder, but can't do the same with the folder.

is there a way to close Folder Object handle from the script? could not find an answer.

here is part of my code:

```
function createFolder(path, position) {
    var folderName = position +'_'+ fileDetails[2] +'_'+ fileDetails[1];
    var newPath = path +'/'+ folderName;
    var newFolder = new Folder(newPath);    
    newFolder.create(); // shouldnt we close the handle here?

    // solution :)
    delete newFolder;

    return newPath;
    }
```

Comment: nevermind, after deleting entire object of newFolder, everything works fine :)

Comment: If you think this answer may be useful to someone else in the future, you can answer your own question and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to close the handler? I mean your question is not clear.vFirst of all create folder only if not exists. So for checking whether folder exists or not use exists property.

```
if(!newFolder.exists)
    newFolder.create();
```

This will create the folder only if not exists and also not open the folder in explorer or finder.